# android database with just sqlite

Tags: php, android, sqlite, webserver, hosting

I am new at android.
I have some problems with android database and how to deploy it into a server **without develop a web site** for the application.
I want to publish this app into google play after a while.
so an online web server is needed.
Locally woking is useless for me.

So my questions are:

**1)** If and only if with using sqlite database, can i deploy my application into a server to make it accessible ?

**2)** if sqlite is not sufficient for me , then how can use php & mySQl ? and could you please offer me some a kind of hosting services for android applications?

**3)** I want to manage sending notifications from the server and provide communications between devices. Is there any service to provide my needs ?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't...You need to have separate database(sql server/mysql) for your server. And then write some webservice so that you mobile app can communicate with server database.

SqLite is only for mobile device and no server supports it, APIK.